# Export Asp.Panel to PDF?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I want to export Asp.Panel `content(text, GridViews)` with CSS to PDF from C#.NET. I am using iTextSharp and RenderControl with Asp.Panel, but CSS is not rendered in PDF.

How can I solve this problem(with iTextSharp(if is possible) or in another way) ?

**This code generate PDF file:**

```
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        StringReader sr;
        string fileName = "C://pdf/GridView.pdf";

        var doc = new Document(PageSize.A3, 45, 5, 5, 5);
        var pdf = fileName;


        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(pdf, FileMode.Create));


        doc.Open();

        HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
        htmlContext.SetTagFactory(Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
        ICSSResolver cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(false);

        cssResolver.AddCssFile(Server.MapPath("Content/PDFs.css"), true);
        IPipeline pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, new PdfWriterPipeline(doc, writer)));

        XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
        XMLParser xmlParse = new XMLParser(true, worker);

        this.pnlTabs.RenderControl(htw);
        sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
        xmlParse.Parse(sr);
        xmlParse.Flush();
        doc.Close();
```

**This is the ASP Panel I want to send to PDF:**

```
     <asp:Panel ID="pnlTabs" runat="server" CssClass="TeamTabs">

        <div class="repHeader">
            <div class="row">
                <div style="padding:12px;border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;margin-bottom:1px;overflow:hidden;">
                    <div class="col4">
                        <p> <font size="4.5"> <b>Client Scorecard</b> </font>  <br>
                            Run Date: 11/1/2013 4:20:01 AM <br>
                            For Dates: 9/12013 - 10/31/2013 <br>
                            Oct 2013 - Filed to Service Complete: 31.18 <br>
                            Oct 2013 - State Average: 34.45 
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <p style="text-align: center;  margin-top:1px"> <font size="3.5"> <b> BECKER POLIAKOFF (CORAL GABLES) </b> 

                        </font> </p>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row" style="padding-bottom:36px;">
            <div class="col9 col-first">
                <asp:GridView ID="gvDashRep_Left_first" runat="server"  ></asp:GridView>
                <asp:GridView ID="gvDashRep_Left_second" runat="server"  ></asp:GridView>
                <asp:GridView ID="gvDashRep_Left_third" runat="server"  ></asp:GridView>
            </div>

            <div class="col3">
                <asp:GridView ID="gvDashRep_Right_first" runat="server"  ></asp:GridView>
                <asp:GridView ID="gvDashRep_Right_second" runat="server"  ></asp:GridView>
                <asp:GridView ID="gvDashRep_Right_third" runat="server"  ></asp:GridView>
            </div>
                <p style="text-align: center;  margin-top:1px"> <font size="2.5"> *For B/W, items with an asterisk indicate that higer number for Octomber 2013 is considered better. </font> </p>
            <div class="col12 col-first">
                <asp:GridView ID="gvComments" runat="server"  ></asp:GridView>
            </div>
        </div>

    </asp:Panel>
```

CSS File
div.row { min-height: 1%;  width: 966px; margin: 0 auto; overflow: hidden; }
div.col3 {width:219px; float: left; margin-left: 30px;}

Comment: Try adding back in the line that points to your css file  cssResolver.AddCssFile(Server.MapPath("Content/pv-telerik-skin/Grid.provest.css"), true); and see if it generates then

Answer (score 0):

There is an additional download (XMLWorker) if you want to export to pdf using ITextSharp with css. You can get the XMLWorker from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/xmlworker/)

To set this up to apply your css you need to do something like the following

```
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    StringReader sr;
    string fileName = Server.MapPath("PATH TO PDF");

    var doc = new Document(PageSize.A3, 45, 5, 5, 5);
    var pdf = fileName;


        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(pdf,             FileMode.Create));

        doc.Open();

        HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
        htmlContext.SetTagFactory(Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
        ICSSResolver cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(false);

        cssResolver.AddCssFile(Server.MapPath("PATH TO CSS"), true);
        IPipeline pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, new PdfWriterPipeline(doc, writer)));

        XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
        XMLParser xmlParse = new XMLParser(true, worker);

        control.RenderControl(htw);
        sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
        xmlParse.Parse(sr);
        xmlParse.Flush();
```

Replace the `PATH TO PDF` (loacation to save the file) and `PATH TO CSS` (location were your css file is) with the relevant file paths. When I had to do this the css file had to be a external file (.css).

Comment: I ai comment: //cssResolver.AddCssFile(Server.MapPath("PATH TO CSS"), true);  I receive ERR : Invalid nested tag p found, expected closing tag br. ! At line: xmlParse.Parse(sr);

Comment: You'll get errors like that if your html tags are not properly formatted or closed if you post your .aspx page I will see if I can spot the issue

Comment: This is the ASP Panel I want to send to PDF:

Comment: I post my .aspx page at Answers. Thanks.

Comment: The issue is with aspx page on the line Oct 2013 - Filed to Service Complete: 31.18 <br>. The <br> tag needs to be <br/> for the parser to read it and see it as a closed tag. Try it and let me know if you get any other errors

Comment: Now generate PDF file, but I can not open it (is damaged).

Comment: Edit you post to show your C# code where you are creating your pdf and sending back to the browser or saving it.

Comment: If I close VS.NET, I can open the PDF file.

Comment: Try placing s break point after you close the document and see if anything still has a reference to the file. Something within your code must not be letting go of the file properly.

Comment: If I Use: cssResolver.AddCssFile(Server.MapPath("Content/PDFs.css"), true);  - The PDF file will not take the CSS.

Comment: Try  cssResolver.AddCssFile(Server.MapPath("~/Content/PDFs.css"), true);